# Copy only the folders (and all their content) at the level of source path with rsync

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync

I have the following tree, where `f` are files while `src` and `d` are directories (`f` could be hidden or not):

```
src/f1
src/f2
...
src/d1
src/d2
src/d3
...
```

I want to replicate the same structure in a `dst` folder, but exclude all files present in the `src` folder (that is `f1`, `f2`, etc. in the tree above, but NOT the content of `d1`, `d2`, `d3` and the other folders). In other words, I want to copy from `src` to `dst` only the folders and all their content (files, folders, link, devices, etc.).

I must use `rsync` and preferably only a `--exclude-from` file (but any other way using `rsync` are welcome).

I tried to put `/*` in the exclusion's file, since `/` allows me to anchor at `src` and `*` means "match all things except slahes (`/`)", but it results in an empty `dst` folder.

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you try something ? Did you search ? Or is it your school homework ?

Comment: @user4089 yes, I tried something (see above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man rsync say :

> `option --filter=RULE, -f        add a file-filtering RULE`

So, try

`rsync -avr -f"+ */" -f"- *" /src/ /dest/`

`-f"+ */"` will add directories when `-f"- *"` will remove files everywhere.

As @Kusalananda said, this will avoid any file in all subtree.

`rsync -avr -f"+ */" -f"- /*" /src/ /dest/`
or

`rsync -avr --include="*/" --exclude="/*" /src/ /dest/`
will sync files in tree subdirs.

Comment: Wouldn't that exclusion rule also exclude files in any other subdirectory, not just files from `/src`? Using the ordinay filtering options, I think you should be able to work around it with `--include='*/'` and `--exclude='/*'` (i.e., include all subdiretories, but exclude anyting from the top `/src` directory not previously included).

Comment: @Kusalananda You're right ! I didn't pay attention to the "but NOT the content of d1, ...". I update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Excluding everything in the source directory with `/*` works, you only need to include the directories again:

```
sudo rsync -av --include='/*/' --exclude='/*' src/ dest
```

- `--exclude='/*'` excludes all files/directories in the source directory
- `--include='/*/'` overrides the exclude and includes directories in the source directory again, must be written before the exclude
- `-a` archive mode, shortcut for `-rlptgoD`

  - `-r` recurse into directories
  - `-l` copy symlinks as symlinks
  - `-p` preserve permissions
  - `-t` preserve modification times
  - `-g` preserve group
  - `-o` preserve owner (super-user only)
  - `-D` preserve device files (super-user only) / special files
- `-v` increase verbosity